# splitting table data into different pages with page numbers

Tags: php, html

I have fetched and stored the database values(depending on conditions) in array form i.e user[], and i have printed them in table.
But when i have upto 500 data stored in array, i want to print it in pages.Is it possible to split and print the data having 10 entries per page? If yes plz help me.

This is my code for fetching the data from database, and assigning to array user[]:

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT inc_patientName,inc_patientAge FROM incident_main WHERE ((inc_patientWard='$ward') AND(inc_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'))ORDER BY inc_patientName ");
$c=mysql_num_rows($sql2);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
$user[]=$row;
}
```

Here I print array in table:

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="500" class="tblListForm">
<tr class="tableheader">

<td>Patient Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr><?php

  foreach($user as $item)
 {
$inc_patientName=$item['inc_patientName']; 
 $inc_patientAge=$item["inc_patientAge"]; 
 ?>
<tr>


<td><?php echo $item["inc_patientName"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item["inc_patientAge"]; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
}?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use mysql `LIMIT` to create a pagination.

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
$start = 5 + 50 * ($page - 1);
$rows = 50;
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM table WHERE ... LIMIT $start, $rows";
```

This will only select row 6-55 from the full result if `$page=1`. In the real case `$start` should be `50*($page-1)` without `5`. `5` is only showed to show how function `LIMIT` works.

Then, you can set `$start` as a `$_GET` parameter in your URL.

In front-end, you may create pagination links like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="page.php?page=1">Page 1</li>
  <li><a href="page.php?page=2">Page 2</li>
</ul>
```

It's esay to create by using php `foreach`. To get page count before showing page, you can select count(*) from table once, then make count divided by 50, and then round it.

Otherwise, you can achieve all 500+ data from database and delivered to front-end, then use plugins(like [jquery datatable](http://www.datatables.net/)) to styling them.

Comment: I have used this but still its not working. the problem is I have a button, only after clicking that the table diplays.even wen i click on page1 i dont get next page, i have to reclick the button. plz help

Comment: You can add`<input name="page" type="text" value="1"/>` to the first page , so when you submit, page parameter will send to next page too. Seems your table shows when recieved some post arguments, so my solution is not working.You can also add your parameters to url, like `page.php?page=1&param1=a&param2=b&param3=c`...

Comment: Thanx a ton!! :) I am really very grateful to u!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is **pagination** of resultset being fetched from the database.

If you have quiet a lot of data stored in backend(say few MBs), it is generally not recommended to fetch all of it in a single go. Instead, *fetch a limited set of records(rows) at first and as user moves to next page, fetch another set of record.*

So instead of doing something like

```
SELECT * from student
```

You should consider doing

```
SELECT * FROM student LIMIT start_from, num_rec_per_page;
```

[This](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html) is a nice tutorial on pagination for PHP and MySQL and [here](http://runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms)'s a working example.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have 3 drop downs where i select , and after pressing this submit button i get that table as output.                                                      <input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="GETREPORT" />.                                                                                 Now the problem is, after using the code which u sent                      echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";  the control goes to that link, but table does not get displayed. Instead 3 dropdownlist appears, where ONLY AFTER PRESSING BUTTON ,I WILL GET NEXT PAGE VALUES.

Answer (score 0):

Definately change your SQL to use LIMIT and OFFSET.

First you only use LIMIT to get the first 10.

```
SELECT inc_patientName,inc_patientAge FROM incident_main WHERE ((inc_patientWard='$ward') AND(inc_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'))ORDER BY inc_patientName LIMIT 10
```

Then on each proceeding request you would use OFFSET by the multiple of 10 that you need. 10, then 20, then 30, and so on.

```
SELECT inc_patientName,inc_patientAge FROM incident_main WHERE ((inc_patientWard='$ward') AND(inc_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'))ORDER BY inc_patientName LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: How will I get the next page?

Comment: You could store the OFFSET value in the session or as @Bandon suggested you can send the value in the GET or POST.

Then you can access the database again each time a new page is selected.